# How to use table view cells, which are not reusable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

**How to use table view cells, which are not reusable?**

My problem:

- **Dynamically** load of text fields (input) for player names

  - based on amount of players (previous ViewController)
- When scrolling down to e.g. player no. 7 (**outside visible cells**) then the **text inputs** of the previous players are **disappearing** and the data is lost

My cell inside **tableView(cellForRowAt)**:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellPlayer" , for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellPlayers
```

How to fix that? I've already found some issues here on stackoverflow but it never worked for me..

[image]

- Image 1: initial state
- Image 2: state after filling out 6 text inputs
- Image 3: scrolling down -> text input 8 gets data of input 1
- Image 4: scrolling up -> its all mixed up

Comment: That is an XY-problem. The real problem is that you are abusing the cell as data source. The data should be stored in an array (or some model object).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But how to store that data into an array? Every text input represents a player. After filling out every input, only then the user can interact with the next View Controller. So the text inputs must stored after every input... how to do that?

Comment: Either use a callback or pass the model (a custom class) to the cell in `cellForRow`. In any case you need to update the model in one of the text field delegate methods. When you are navigating to the next view controller again get the data from the model.

Comment: But how to solve the problem of displaying the data within the text inputs correctly? I've added some pictures for that.

Comment: Why dont just use not reusable cells? Then I could iterate through all of these text inputs, getting the strings and store them into an array. So there will be generated static cells. There is no way to do it like that?

Comment: Because that's the way dynamic cells and the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern works. You can use static cells but then you cannot change the number of cells at runtime (unless you do **everything** in code)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store everything that is written in a model, and in cellForRow you could configure the cell with the saved data.